# Error 2835: The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer

Below is from MSI error log

```
DEBUG: Error 2835:  The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2835. The arguments are: ErrorIcon, ErrorDialog, 
Office 2010 PIA is not installed.
MSI (c) (08:54) [12:57:24:883]: Product: ExcelAddin -- Office 2010 PIA is not installed.

Action ended 12:57:24: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (08:54) [12:57:24:915]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 12:57:24: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 12:57:24: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (08:54) [12:57:24:915]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm' 
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control BannerBmp on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
Info 2898.For VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 13 pixels height.
Info 2898.For VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0 textstyle, the system created a 'MS Sans Serif' font, in 0 character set, of 20 pixels height.
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line1, to the right
DEBUG: Error 2826:  Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, Line2, to the right
Action 12:57:24: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
```

I was doing Excel add-in installation on a virtual pc that runing 64-bit Win7 with Office 2010.  The .net 4 CP, office2010 PIA, and vsto 4 runtime were all included in the installer. According to the error message, it seems that something is preventing office 2010 PIA being installed. Any idea what the error is suggesting here? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the installer tries to display an error message to you, but it fails because `ErrorIcon` standard control is not found on the `ErrorDialog`. Make sure `ErrorDialog` contains `ErrorIcon` control.

Answer (score 1):

Having this same issue, and it appears the REAL error comes BEFORE this.

My error was from my custom Installer class, so if you have one of those you should investigate there.

Reference: [Error 2835: The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog ErrorDialog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/5958b64a-6083-4327-bb94-4c3c90626f51/)

After looking closely at my install log, I found Error 2826 (Line on ConfirmInstallForm extends beyond the boundaries) and 2769 (did not close 1 MSIHANDLES) also.